# Is there a way in Fluent Validation library to remove the index from the collection validation errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm using Fluent Validation to validate this model:

```
class MyModel {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<ChildModel> Children {get; set;}
}

class ChildModel {
    public int CId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

If I added a validation like:

```
public class MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Children)
            .SetValidator(new ChildValidator());
    }
}
public class ChildValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildModel>
{
    public ChildValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

This model and validators, in case of validation errors, will give this response:

```
{
        .....
        "Children[0].Name": [
            "'Name' must not be empty."
        ],
        "Children[1].Name": [
            "'Name` must not be empty."
        ]
        .....
}
```

I would like to know how to replace `Children` in the validation response with the `CId` value of the same item that the validation failed for it, like this:

```
{
        .....
        "12345[0].Name": [
            "'Name' must not be empty."
        ],
        "99887[1].Name": [
            "'Name` must not be empty."
        ]
        .....
}
```

`12345` and `99887` are the value of the `CId` of items in `Children` (item in index 0 and item in index 1).

Comment: Tried overriding property name as mentioned in https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/configuring.html#overriding-the-property-name ?

Comment: ```ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver``` will effect ALL the system, I think I will need to check the model type because the use case I have is for a specific model not all of the models I'm validating.
And I tried to override the property name specifically for the validation I need, it won't remove the index, nor overriding the display name will.

Comment: What is "My Item Id Value"? It is a little difficult to answer this question without some real property names, or at least made-up meaningful names.

Comment: @GregBurghardt added more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Validation messages inside a foreach statement are default formatted like

```cs
<collectionPropertyName>[<index>].<itemPropertyName>: <error message>
// Example:
// Children[0].Name: 'Name' must not be empty.
```

If you want to modify the 'list prefix', you can

- override the collection property name with `OverridePropertyName()`. You can make it singular for example, but you can't make it empty
- override the indexer with `OverrideIndexer()` and replace the '[0]' with something you like

Example:

```cs
RuleFor(r => r.Children)
  .ForEach(r => r
    .OverrideIndexer((model, collection, element, index) => " " + element.CId?.ToString())
    .SetValidator(new ChildValidator())
  )
  .OverridePropertyName("Child");
// Example:
// Child 1234.Name: 'Name' must not be empty.
```

If the validation messages are not returned with the 'collectionPropertyName[index]' format to the using code (api, unit test, ..) and you want to manipulate the 'error message' itself, you can override the 'Validate' methods in the child validator class like:

```cs
public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<ChildDto> context)
{
    var result = base.Validate(context);
    result.Errors.ForEach(e => AddMessagePrefix(e, context));
    return result;
}
public override async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<ChildDto> context, CancellationToken cancellation = default)
{
    var result = await base.ValidateAsync(context, cancellation);
    result.Errors.ForEach(e => AddMessagePrefix(e, context));
    return result;
}
private void AddMessagePrefix(ValidationFailure failure, ValidationContext<ChildDto> context)
{
    if (context.InstanceToValidate != null)
        failure.ErrorMessage = $"Child {context.InstanceToValidate.CId}: {failure.ErrorMessage}";
}
// Example:
// Child 1234: 'Name' must not be empty.
```